# Getting error 401 response for requests to an Apigee API

Tags: angularjs, rest, apigee

I am trying to make requests to an Apigee API from an Angular service. It works with Postman, but I am getting `401` unauthorized error when making requests to the API from my Angular code.

Here is the Angular code I am trying:

```
$http({
       url: "https://xxx_test.com/data?sdate=date",
       method: "GET",
       headers: {
               'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'                             
             },
     })
```

This is the response that I am getting :

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.apikey","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}}}

Comment: Have u tried to set the content-type header? Most api's wont work correctly without it

Comment: try changing the header to `"APIKey"` instead of `"apikey"`

Comment: Kris & Aleksey Solovey, I have tried both suggestions but it's not working. I am unable to understand that how it is working with postman. do you have any idea? Please suggest.

Comment: Please share console logs and network log as it is

Comment: @manishkumar- Network log:
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.apikey","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}}}

Console log:
angular.js:12265 OPTIONS https://apiurl?start_date=04/26/2018&end_date=04/26/2018 401 (Unauthorized) 
:3000/#/pos:1 Failed to load https://apiurl?start_date=04/26/2018&end_date=04/26/2018: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was on server side configuration. We are using apigee for our API so it needs some configuration for CORS.

Here is settings :

```
<FaultResponse>
        <Set>
            <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
            <ReasonPhrase>CORS OK</ReasonPhrase>
            <Headers>
                <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods">GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH</Header>
                <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin">*</Header>
                <Header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers">authorization,content-type,api-key</Header>
            </Headers>
            <Payload/>
            <!-- Remove default fault content. -->
        </Set>
    </FaultResponse>
```

Add RaisFault policy in your flow with condition.

```
<Condition>request.verb == "OPTIONS" AND request.header.origin != null AND request.header.Access-Control-Request-Method != null</Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way.Also set the accept header.

```
var config = {headers:  {
        'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXX',
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    }
};

$http.get("https://xxx_test.com/data?sdate=date", config);
```

Comment: @sandeeppandey can you show the headers being sent in the network tab ,along with the headers in the postman.